# Quasiquotes and Generics in Scala

Tags: scala, scala-macros

I'm using Play Framework and trying to write an action that can parse protobuf request as following:

```
def AsyncProtoAction(block: ProtoRequestA => Future[Result]): Action[AnyContent] = {
    Action.async { request =>
        request.contentType match {
            case Some("application/protobuf") => request.body.asRaw match {
                case Some(raw) => raw.asBytes(1024 * 1024) match {
                    case Some(rawBytes) =>
                        val proto = ProtoRequestA.parseFrom(rawBytes)
                        block(proto)
                    case _ => ...
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here, `ProtoRequestA` is a generated object using `ScalaPB`. It works, however, I have a lot of protobuf request objects. Then I try to rewrite it using macro:

```
object Actions {
  def AsyncProtoAction[T](block: T => Future[Result]): 
        Action[AnyContent] = macro asyncProtoAction_impl[T]

  def asyncProtoAction_impl[T: c.WeakTypeTag](c: blackbox.Context)
       (block: c.Tree) = { import c.universe._
    val protoType = weakTypeOf[T]
    q"""import play.api.mvc._
        Action.async { request =>
          request.contentType match {
            case Some("application/protobuf") =>
              request.body.asRaw match {
                case Some(raw) =>
                  raw.asBytes(1024 * 1024) match {
                    case Some(rawBytes) =>
                      val proto = $protoType.parseFrom(rawBytes)
                      $block(proto)
                    case _ => ...
                  }
              }
          }
        }"""
  }
}
```

This doesn't work. The compilation error is `value parseFrom is not a member of packageName.ProtoRequestA`.

I tried `showRaw(tq"$protoType")` in REPL, which output `String = TypeTree()`. I guess the correct output should be `String = Select(Ident(TermName("packageName")), TypeName("ProtoRequestA"))`. So what should I do?

Comment: Try to replace `$protoType` with `${protoType.typeSymbol.companionSymbol}` and see how it goes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've identified the problem, which is that when you interpolate the `ProtoRequestA` type you get something different from the `ProtoRequestA` companion object. One easy solution is to interpolate the symbol of the companion object, which you can get from the type's symbol. Here's a simplified example:

```
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox.Context

def companionObjectBarImpl[A: c.WeakTypeTag](c: Context): c.Tree = {
  import c.universe._
  q"${ symbolOf[A].companion }.bar"
}

def companionObjectBar[A]: Int = macro companionObjectBarImpl[A]
```

This macro will work on any type with a companion object with a `bar` method that returns an `Int`. For example:

```
scala> class Foo; object Foo { def bar = 10 }
defined class Foo
defined object Foo

scala> companionObjectBar[Foo]
res0: Int = 10
```

You should be able to do something similar.